# "juju status" error on machines which are already in "allocated" state

Tags: juju, maas, cloud, canonical

I have two VMs in my MAAS setup: node0 and node1

- Status of both of these machines are "Allocated to root".
- Another VM with name "node_juju" was created and "commissioned" through MAAS.
- With "node_juju" in "ready" state, I ran "juju bootstrap" command on host.
- The command ran successfully.
- Deployment of Juju GUI charm was also successful: "juju deploy juju-gui --to 0".
- I can access the Juju GUI as well.
- "juju deploy wordpress", "juju deploy mysql", "juju add-relation wordpress mysql" and "juju expose wordpress" commands were then issued.

So far so good. However issue which I am facing is that "juju status" is showing following output for node0 and node1

```
agent-state-info: 'cannot run instances: gomaasapi: got error back from server:
  409 CONFLICT (No matching node is available.)'
```

I suspect that since node0 and node1 were already part of MAAS envoironment (in allocated state), juju bootstrap could not identified them. If this assumption is correct, then how can I add these machines such that Juju can identify them and thus spawn services on them?
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju asks MAAS for a new machine, but both machines are already allocated as you indicate, so MAAS doesn't have any machine available to hand off to juju. Juju doesn't keep an inventory of what's available in MAAS, it just asks MAAS to get a new machine with a set of constraints.

You have commission your machines and then deploy wordpress.

I hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: That's great, would you mark the answer as correct?, so people can find it easily :), thanks

Comment: @feipe: Done :)